# InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unknown entity: UserWithRoles

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a Spring Boot project using spring security, and when I edit the user I get an InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException and a traceback. Below is the full message:

2020-06-04 09:35:58.542 ERROR 13591 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unknown entity: com.progeny.model.UserWithRoles; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.progeny.model.UserWithRoles] with root cause

Here is the code of the controller:

```
// --------- ADD FRIEND (POST)------------
@PostMapping("/profile/friends/edit")
public String addFriend(@RequestParam long friendId, Model model) {

    User currentUser = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal(); //1. Get the current user

    User friend = usersRepo.getUserById(friendId);

    System.out.println(currentUser.getFirstName());
    System.out.println(friend.getFirstName());

    if(friend.getFriends() == null){ // if there is no friends list -->

        List<User> newFriends = new ArrayList<>(); // 1. Make a new friends list
        friend.setFriends(newFriends); // 2. give the new friends list to User

    }
    if(currentUser.getFriends() == null){ // if there is no friends list -->

        List<User> newFriends = new ArrayList<>(); // 1. Make a new friends list
        currentUser.setFriends(newFriends); // 2. give the new friends list to User

    }

    // --------- ADD USER TO FRIEND-----------
    currentUser.getFriends().add(friend);

    System.out.println(currentUser.getFriends().get(0).getUsername());

    // --------- ADD FRIEND TO USER------------
    friend.getFriends().add(currentUser);

    System.out.println(friend.getFriends().get(0).getUsername());

    // --------- SAVE TO DB -----------
    usersRepo.save(currentUser); // 3. save the list of users to the current users information
    usersRepo.save(friend); // 3. save the list of users to the current users information

    return "users/showConnections";
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that "SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()" Does not return a User object it returns a UserWithRoles object. The UserWithRoles was used to set the currentuser variable. Then the code tried to save currentuser using the userRepo, which of course crashed because it was not a User object. It was a UserWithRoles, that did not fit in the space for a User.

This is the change I made:

```
User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal(); //1. Get the current user
User currentUser = new User(user);
```